# Resources for periodical economics feed

Tags: macroeconomics, microeconomics, financial-economics, markets

I'm learning economics and I want to read/hear the world through the lenses of any economist.

What are the best periodical economics news feeds?
It could

1. Magazines such as theeconomist.com
2. Podcast etc.

Thank you,
Karsnen